# Hide content when input content is removed (manually)

Tags: jquery

I have a live search box which works fine except if the user deletes the content, the content doesn't hide itself.

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name=filter]').attr('autocomplete','off');
  $("#filter").keyup(function(){
   var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
   $(".country li").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
     $(this).fadeOut();
    } else {
     $(this).show();
     $('#call-content').show();
     count++;
    }
   });
  });
 });
 $( "#clear" ).click(function() {
  $('#filter').val('');
  $('#call-content').hide();
 });
```

JSfiddle with the HTML [here](http://jsfiddle.net/byxq9/)

Comment: fiddle seems to be working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a few changes: **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byxq9/3/).**

Firstly, the `$('#call-content').show()` is moved outside of the conditional, and executes on any keystroke.

Secondly, i changed your condition to also check for the absence of a value in `#filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to empty the search result field if search result text is empty.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=filter]').attr('autocomplete','off');
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()){
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        $(".country li").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
           $(this).fadeOut();
        } else {
           $(this).show();
           $('#call-content').show();
           count++;
        }
       });
      } else{
      $('#call-content').empty();
      }
   });

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byxq9/4/)**

You just need to add condition of empty text.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=filter]').attr('autocomplete','off');
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){
        $('#call-content').show();
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        $(".country li").each(function(){
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0 || filter == '') {
                $(this).hide();   
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });
    });

});
```